# Chaptertitle boxed in twoside book-document

Tags: tikz-pgf, titlesec, double-sided

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\large\bfseries}{\thesection\quad}{0pt}{#1}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection\quad}{0pt}{#1}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]{\large\bfseries}{\quad}{0pt}{#1}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{2pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

%define chapter-title
\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\Large\bfseries\scshape}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-5cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=gray!15, draw=gray] (0,0) rectangle (0.9\paperwidth,3cm);     
    \node[anchor=east,yshift=1.5cm,xshift=0.9\paperwidth, text width=1.05\textwidth]{\textnormal{\textbf{\huge{#1}}}};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\chapter{Two}
\chapter{Three}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Hi,

I want the gray box always to begin/end at the **inner side** of a page, so that it is **mirrored** if there are two chapters on consecutive pages (see page 2 and 3). Any ideas?

Thanks Nico

Comment: Please, edit the question and remove of the `\` before the brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `\ifthispageodd{}{}` macro of the Komma-Script bundle you can test when the page is odd and therefore change the definition of the chapter.

You did not say what to do with the name of the chapter. In this case stays on the left. If you will like to mirror the position the `\node` macro also should be changed.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\large\bfseries}{\thesection\quad}{0pt}{#1}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection\quad}{0pt}{#1}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]{\large\bfseries}{\quad}{0pt}{#1}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{2pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

%define chaptertitle-style
\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\Large\bfseries\scshape}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-5cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \ifthispageodd{%
          \draw[fill=gray!15, draw=gray] (0,0) rectangle
          (0.9\paperwidth,3cm);       
          \node[anchor=east,yshift=1.5cm,xshift=0.9\paperwidth, text width=1.05\textwidth]{\textbf{\huge{#1}}};
          }%
          {
          \draw[fill=gray!15, draw=gray] (0.1\paperwidth,0) rectangle
          (1\paperwidth,3cm);       
          \node[anchor=east,yshift=1.5cm,xshift=0.9\paperwidth, text width=1.05\textwidth]{\textbf{\huge{#1}}};
          }
        \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\chapter{Two}
\chapter{Three}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\large\bfseries}{\thesection\quad}{0pt}{#1}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection\quad}{0pt}{#1}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]{\large\bfseries}{\quad}{0pt}{#1}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{2pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

%define chaptertitle-style
\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\Large\bfseries\scshape}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-5cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \ifthispageodd{
          \draw[fill=gray!15, draw=gray] (0,0) rectangle (0.9\paperwidth,3cm);       
          \node[anchor=east,yshift=1.5cm,xshift=0.9\paperwidth, text width=1.05\textwidth]{\textbf{\huge{#1}}};
          }
          {
          \draw[fill=gray!15, draw=gray] (0.1\paperwidth,0) rectangle(1\paperwidth,3cm);       
          \node[anchor=east,yshift=1.5cm,xshift=0.9\paperwidth, text width=1.05\textwidth]{\textbf{\huge{#1}}};
          }
        \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }

%adjust spacing for correct alignment of following text
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}
\blindtext[4]
\chapter{Two}
\blindtext[4]
\chapter{Three}
\blindtext[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is a working example for my problem referring to the solution TeXtnik gave.